# Can't open a notebook in Workbench 2 with Mathematica 10

Tags: workbench

I don't think this question is a duplicate. Posted answers that I found did not solve my problem.

Conditions: Win8.1 *Mathematica* 10, Workbench 2

As I mentioned above, I can't open a .nb file in Worbench 2 using external *Mathematica*.

The error message for debugin in *Mathematica* is

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Test.nb".
com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)J
```

The error message for openning in *Mathematica* is

```
An internal error occurred during: "FrontEnd Job::Open Notebook".
com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)J
```

PS: All above works pretty well on another computer of mine. I don't know why.

Comment: Is your other computer on mma10?  Workbench 2 doesn't work very well with mma10.  Every is getting frustrated with waiting for WB3 to come out which has been in very extended beta.

Comment: If you contact `support@wolfram.com` they will send you the beta version of WB3, which should solve this issue.

Comment: @Stefan R Is this still the case? After all WRI tells potential customers that Workbench 2.0 ist [compatible with all Versions of Mathematica Version 6 and higher](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/qa/) and a benefit of premier service. In my country that would amount to false advertisment and thus meat criteria for unfair business practices if it were still the case ...